# TCP Window Scaling Problem over MPLS

Tags: tcp, mpls, linux

After extensive troubleshooting why the TCP speed over an MPLS circuit is slow in one direction, I figured out that by adjusting the TCP window size the situation improved a lot. Maybe you can tell me why.

Details:

- The ping between both hosts is 7ms
- Both machines run Debian Wheezy with kernel 3.2.0-4
- Both machines have default TCP settings
- Both
  machines have an 10 Gbps uplink

Results with the default TCP Settings:

*Location A -> Location B:* `iperf -c $Location B --> ~2 Gbps`

*Location B -> Location A*: `iperf -c $Location A --> 65 - 250 Mbps`

After applying the following changes to */etc/sysctl.conf* I experienced much better results

```
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096        16384   16777216
```

Results after adjusted TCP Settings:

*Location A -> Location B:* `iperf -c $Location B --> ~2 Gbps`

*Location B -> Location A*: `iperf -c $Location A --> 150 Mbps - 2 Gbps` (mostly ~1.8 Gbps)

My question is what might negatively affect the TCP window scaling? Here is the output of a *tcptrace* I have recorded. Maybe it helps to identify the problem.

Thank you for your help!

Regards,
Leon Kramer

```
#
# Speed: ~2 Gbps
#

1 arg remaining, starting with 'tcpdump.lol'
Ostermann's tcptrace -- version 6.6.7 -- Thu Nov  4, 2004

260307 packets seen, 260307 TCP packets traced
elapsed wallclock time: 0:00:17.740455, 14673 pkts/sec analyzed
trace file elapsed time: 0:00:03.798052
TCP connection info:
2 TCP connections traced:
================================
TCP connection 2:
    host c:        10.1.2.5:59242
    host d:        10.1.2.2:5201
    complete conn: RESET    (SYNs: 2)  (FINs: 0)
    first packet:  Thu Nov 13 00:05:18.256992 2014
    last packet:   Thu Nov 13 00:05:21.876883 2014
    elapsed time:  0:00:03.619891
    total packets: 260276
    filename:      tcpdump.lol
   c->d:                  d->c:
     total packets:        156463           total packets:        103813      
     resets sent:               0           resets sent:             154      
     ack pkts sent:        156462           ack pkts sent:        103660      
     pure acks sent:            1           pure acks sent:       103658      
     sack pkts sent:            0           sack pkts sent:         8716      
     dsack pkts sent:           0           dsack pkts sent:           6      
     max sack blks/ack:         0           max sack blks/ack:         1      
     unique bytes sent: 674405781           unique bytes sent:         0      
     actual data pkts:     156461           actual data pkts:          0      
     actual data bytes: 674415917           actual data bytes:         0      
     rexmt data pkts:           6           rexmt data pkts:           0      
     rexmt data bytes:      10136           rexmt data bytes:          0      
     zwnd probe pkts:           0           zwnd probe pkts:           0      
     zwnd probe bytes:          0           zwnd probe bytes:          0      
     outoforder pkts:        3784           outoforder pkts:           0      
     pushed data pkts:         28           pushed data pkts:          0      
     SYN/FIN pkts sent:       1/0           SYN/FIN pkts sent:       1/0      
     req 1323 ws/ts:          Y/Y           req 1323 ws/ts:          Y/Y      
     adv wind scale:            7           adv wind scale:            7      
     req sack:                  Y           req sack:                  Y      
     sacks sent:                0           sacks sent:             8716      
     urgent data pkts:          0 pkts      urgent data pkts:          0 pkts 
     urgent data bytes:         0 bytes     urgent data bytes:         0 bytes
     mss requested:          1460 bytes     mss requested:          1460 bytes
     max segm size:         14480 bytes     max segm size:             0 bytes
     min segm size:            37 bytes     min segm size:             0 bytes
     avg segm size:          4310 bytes     avg segm size:             0 bytes
     max win adv:           14720 bytes     max win adv:         3145728 bytes
     min win adv:           14720 bytes     min win adv:           14592 bytes
     zero win adv:              0 times     zero win adv:              0 times
     avg win adv:           14720 bytes     avg win adv:         3123096 bytes
     initial window:           37 bytes     initial window:            0 bytes
     initial window:            1 pkts      initial window:            0 pkts 
     ttl stream length:        NA           ttl stream length:        NA      
     missed data:              NA           missed data:              NA      
     truncated data:            0 bytes     truncated data:            0 bytes
     truncated packets:         0 pkts      truncated packets:         0 pkts 
     data xmit time:        3.612 secs      data xmit time:        0.000 secs 
     idletime max:           43.3 ms        idletime max:           43.3 ms   
     throughput:        186305549 Bps       throughput:                0 Bps  


====================================================================================

#
# Speed: ~65 Mbps
#

1 arg remaining, starting with 'tcpdump.lol'
Ostermann's tcptrace -- version 6.6.7 -- Thu Nov  4, 2004

652370 packets seen, 652370 TCP packets traced
elapsed wallclock time: 0:00:07.985123, 81698 pkts/sec analyzed
trace file elapsed time: 0:02:13.121598
TCP connection info:
2 TCP connections traced:
================================
TCP connection 2:
    host c:        10.1.2.2:45259
    host d:        10.1.2.5:5201
    complete conn: RESET    (SYNs: 2)  (FINs: 1)
    first packet:  Wed Nov 12 22:42:06.606682 2014
    last packet:   Wed Nov 12 22:44:19.553859 2014
    elapsed time:  0:02:12.947177
    total packets: 652339
    filename:      tcpdump.lol
   c->d:                  d->c:
     total packets:        446774           total packets:        205565      
     resets sent:               0           resets sent:              22      
     ack pkts sent:        446773           ack pkts sent:        205543      
     pure acks sent:            1           pure acks sent:       205541      
     sack pkts sent:            0           sack pkts sent:         9322      
     dsack pkts sent:           0           dsack pkts sent:           2      
     max sack blks/ack:         0           max sack blks/ack:         3      
     unique bytes sent: 1058366405           unique bytes sent:         0      
     actual data pkts:     446772           actual data pkts:          0      
     actual data bytes: 1058379437           actual data bytes:         0      
     rexmt data pkts:           5           rexmt data pkts:           0      
     rexmt data bytes:      13032           rexmt data bytes:          0      
     zwnd probe pkts:           0           zwnd probe pkts:           0      
     zwnd probe bytes:          0           zwnd probe bytes:          0      
     outoforder pkts:        1577           outoforder pkts:           0      
     pushed data pkts:       5733           pushed data pkts:          0      
     SYN/FIN pkts sent:       1/0           SYN/FIN pkts sent:       1/1      
     req 1323 ws/ts:          Y/Y           req 1323 ws/ts:          Y/Y      
     adv wind scale:            7           adv wind scale:            7      
     req sack:                  Y           req sack:                  Y      
     sacks sent:                0           sacks sent:             9322      
     urgent data pkts:          0 pkts      urgent data pkts:          0 pkts 
     urgent data bytes:         0 bytes     urgent data bytes:         0 bytes
     mss requested:          1460 bytes     mss requested:          1460 bytes
     max segm size:         18824 bytes     max segm size:             0 bytes
     min segm size:            37 bytes     min segm size:             0 bytes
     avg segm size:          2368 bytes     avg segm size:             0 bytes
     max win adv:           14720 bytes     max win adv:          561920 bytes
     min win adv:           14720 bytes     min win adv:           14592 bytes
     zero win adv:              0 times     zero win adv:              0 times
     avg win adv:           14720 bytes     avg win adv:          533768 bytes
     initial window:           37 bytes     initial window:            0 bytes
     initial window:            1 pkts      initial window:            0 pkts 
     ttl stream length:        NA           ttl stream length:         0 bytes
     missed data:              NA           missed data:               0 bytes
     truncated data:            0 bytes     truncated data:            0 bytes
     truncated packets:         0 pkts      truncated packets:         0 pkts 
     data xmit time:      132.940 secs      data xmit time:        0.000 secs 
     idletime max:           37.8 ms        idletime max:           37.8 ms   
     throughput:          7960804 Bps       throughput:                0 Bps
```

Comment: Have you talked to the MPLS provider? tcp window modification shouldn't be necessary for the distance that 7ms represents.

Comment: Yes, according to them they do not see any problem. However, switches do not show any errors.

Comment: I suspect the two end systems are not identical or the networking configuration at your sites differs. You might want to try the test again and avoid as much middleware as you can. Plug directly into the WAN routers at the sites. A provider issue is possible but unlikely.

Comment: At one endpoint of the MPLs there is Flow Control enabled, at the other site it is disabled. However, firstly, there are many routers from the MPLS provider in between and secondly, the counter does not show any PAUSE Frames for that link. Could this be an issue, though?

Comment: I don't know. Eliminate all variation.

Comment: Maybe look at / post a Stevens Sequence Graph (can be done from wireshark of the two transfers.) Also maybe set the data to be transferred via iperf to be the same total size to make things clearer.

Comment: Did you check local network performance? May be iperf from one local server to another local server? It looks like a bad optical cord. Any errors on switch interface?